# What type to use for a timeout variable in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

**When writing a function in C++ that takes a timeout as one of its arguments, what type should I use for the timeout argument itself?**

An example of such a function might be:

```
void my_function(bool work_really_hard, timeout_type timeout)
{
// Do stuff, until timeout is reached.
}
```

I have thought about using `std::chrono::seconds` for `timeout_type`, but that disallows using any timeout in the sub-second realm.

When using `std::chrono::nanoseconds` instead, it is cumbersome to specify, say, 10 minutes.

Any way to resolve this in a reasonable way, while keeping the function signature and calls neat and simple?

Comment: use the `wait_until` or `sleep_until` primitives? IOW, use a deadline instead of a timeout

Comment: @sehe The internals of how the timeout is obeyed are not relevant for this question (I don't have any control over them). I'm just concerned about what type to use for the timeout in the function signature.

Comment: How about milliseconds? It is _kinda_ standard to specify timeouts in milliseconds. Also - `std::chrono` types are expressed in ratios, so you can use non-integer values.

Comment: My point is, you can derive your deadline in whatever fashion you prefer, so there is no longer an API restriction on that regard

Comment: Perhaps take `std::chrono::duration` - the same thing that, say, `sleep_for` takes?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Doesn't that involve making a `template<class Rep, class Period>` out of my function, in other words, instantiating a new function for every duration type it is called with? Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> When using std::chrono::nanoseconds instead, it is cumbersome to
>   specify, say, 10 minutes.

Actually, it doesn't make it cumbersome in the least:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void my_function(bool work_really_hard, std::chrono::nanoseconds timeout)
{
    std::cout << timeout.count() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    my_function(true, std::chrono::minutes(10));
}
```

Output:

```
600000000000
```

The only time you'll have trouble with `nanoseconds` is if you want to pass in something that won't exactly convert to `nanoseconds`, such as `picoseconds`, or `duration<long, ratio<1, 3>>` (1/3 second units).

**Update**

I intended this answer to be additional information for an already accepted answer that I thought was a good answer (by sehe).  sehe recommended a templated solution, which I also consider fine.

If you want to accept **any** `std::chrono::duration`, even one that you may have to [truncate or round](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/duration_io/chrono_util.html), then going with sehe's deleted answer is the way to go:

```
template <typename Rep, typename Period>
void my_function(bool work_really_hard, std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> timeout)
{
    // Do stuff, until timeout is reached.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout);
}
```

If for some reason you do not want to deal with templates and/or you are content with having your clients having to specify only units that are exactly convertible to `std::chrono:nanoseconds`, then using `std::chrono:nanoseconds` as I show above is also completely acceptable.

All of the `std::chrono` "pre-defined" units:

```
hours
minutes
seconds
milliseconds
microseconds
nanoseconds
```

are implicitly convertible to `nanoseconds`, and will not involve any truncation or round off error.  Overflow will not happen as long as you keep it within the two bright white lines (obscure reference to keeping your car in your own lane).  As long as the duration is within +/- 292 years, you don't have to worry about overflow with these pre-defined units.

The std-defined functions such as `std::this_thread::sleep_for` are templated as sehe suggests for exactly the reason of wanting to be interoperable with every `chrono:duration` imaginable (e.g. 1/3 of a floating-point femtosecond).  It is up to the API designer to decide if they need that much flexibility in their own API.

If I've now managed to confuse you instead of clarify, don't worry too much.  If you choose to use `nanoseconds`, things will either work exactly, with no truncation or round off error, or the client will get a compile time error.  There will be **no** run time error.

```
void my_function(bool work_really_hard, std::chrono::nanoseconds timeout)
{
    std::cout << timeout.count() << '\n';
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    typedef duration<double, pico> picoseconds;
    my_function(true, picoseconds(100000.25));
}

test.cpp:15:9: error: no matching function for call to 'my_function'
        my_function(true, picoseconds(100000.25));
        ^~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:4:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'duration<double, ratio<[...], 1000000000000>>' to
      'duration<long long, ratio<[...], 1000000000>>' for 2nd argument
    void my_function(bool work_really_hard, std::chrono::nanoseconds timeout)
         ^
1 error generated.
```

And if the client gets a compile-time error, he can always use `duration_cast` to work around it:

```
my_function(true, duration_cast<nanoseconds>(picoseconds(100000.25)));  // Ok
```

For further details, please see:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm

Sweet update to the original code at the top of this answer.  In C++1y, which we hope means C++14:

```
using namespace std::literals;
my_function(true, 10min);  // also ok, is equal to 600000000000 nanoseconds
```

**Question:** What would you recommend as a timeout of "infinity" (i.e. don't time out)

I would first try to use an API that didn't take a timeout, and which implied "doesn't time out."  For example `condition_variable::wait`.  If I had control over the API, I would create such a signature without a timeout.

Failing that, I would create a series a "large" `chrono::durations`:

```
using days = std::chrono::duration
<
    std::int32_t, std::ratio_multiply<std::chrono::hours::period, std::ratio<24>>
>;

using weeks = std::chrono::duration
<
    std::int32_t, std::ratio_multiply<days::period, std::ratio<7>>
>;

using years = std::chrono::duration
<
    std::int32_t, std::ratio_multiply<days::period, std::ratio<146097, 400>>
>;

using months = std::chrono::duration
<
    std::int32_t, std::ratio_divide<years::period, std::ratio<12>>
>;
```

And then I would use one of these large durations in my call, for example:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(years(3));
```

I would not try to push_things to the maximum (you might break the underlying assumptions the OS has made for example).  Just arbitrarily pick something ridiculously large (like 3 years).  That will catch your code reviewer's eye, and likely strike up an informative conversation. :-)

Now available in video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M :-)

Comment: +1 this should be the accepted answer. This makes so much sense I'm now embarassed :)

Comment: I'll accept this answer and admit I feel embarrassed for not trying something so obvious. `std::chrono::duration` indeed [has constructors that take other duration types as their arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration).

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer more than once, your update is really appreciated. One tiny follow-up question: What would you recommend as a timeout of "infinity" (i.e. don't time out), if I don't want to use 0 for that, also keeping in mind possible signed/unsigned conversion and overflow issues of the underlying types?

Answer (score 1):

Use a template parameter for the timeout type and expect one of the `std::chrono` types, or something with a similar interface; this will allow you to pass in any unit of time.

```
template<typename T>
void wait_a_while(const T& duration)
{
   std::this_thread::sleep(duration);
}

wait_a_while(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
wait_a_while(std::chrono::milliseconds(30));
```

Comment: Just a heads up, since you arrived at nearly the same answer as I did. Look up for a moment of clarity :)